DeepL API - I am using DeepL .net API for document translation - getting error while translating large file
I have implemented translator using DeepL DotNet API.I am having DeepL Pro account.
I have implemented .net framework web api where I am using deepl Pro account for translation. I am using my web api in my react app
File translation is working fine upto 5MB size.
Below is the error I am getting while translation
Error occurred during document translation: Unexpected request failure: The delegate executed asynchronously through TimeoutPolicy did not complete within the timeout.
How to fix this issue?
After setting below options, I could able to translate file upto 20MB
OverallConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(550),
PerRetryConnectionTimeout=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(250)
But when I tried to translate file of 30 MB I got below error


Well it sounds like you probably need to increase the timeout.

I increased OverallConnectionTimeout and now getting different error - timeout error occured while copying stream content

You should add this information to the question, along with what you've set the timeouts to, how quickly you're observing the error (i.e. how long it's actually taking to time out) and details about how fast you'd expect all the data to be copied. (If this is on a poor network connection that could explain things, for example.)

The DeepL API Pro limit is 30 MB for Word or PDF files:
https://developers.deepl.com/docs/resources/usage-limits

Yes Thats why I tried file upto 30MB. But code is throwing error for above 22MB files

@KanchanKumbhar - They also say they have a limit at 1 million characters. Did you check you are not exceeding that?

Yes. it is not exceeded yet.
